# Dados não são inseridos no sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Galera estou iniciando agora no Android, fui fazer um teste de inserção de dados no banco porém os dados não são inseridos, posso estar enganado em algum momento, segue abaixo o código:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_alunos);
```

Classe responsável por apresentar os alunos na list:

```
    AlunoDAO dao = new AlunoDAO(this);
    List<Aluno> alunos =  dao.buscaAlunos();
    dao.close();

    ListView listaAlunos = ( ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_alunos);


    ArrayAdapter<Aluno> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Aluno>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,alunos);
    listaAlunos.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button novoAluno = (Button) findViewById(R.id.novo_aluno);
```

Classe responsável por inserir e buscar os alunos no banco

```
  public AlunoDAO(Context context) {
    super(context, "Agenda",null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE Alunos (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT NOT NULL, endereco TEXT, site TEXT, nota REAL);";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Alunos";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public void insere(Aluno aluno) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues dados = new ContentValues();
    dados.put("nome",aluno.getNome());
    dados.put("endereco",aluno.getEndereco());
    dados.put("telefone",aluno.getTelefone());
    dados.put("site",aluno.getSite());
    dados.put("nota",aluno.getNota());

    db.insert("Alunos",null,dados);
}

public List<Aluno> buscaAlunos() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Alunos;";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();//getReadableDatabase
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);

    List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        Aluno a = new Aluno();
        a.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
        a.setNome(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")));
        a.setEndereco(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("endereco")));
        a.setTelefone(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("telefone")));
        a.setSite(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("site")));
        a.setNota(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("nota")));
        alunos.add(a);
    }
    c.close();
    return alunos;
}
```

Nenhum erro é apontado, utilizando o debug sempre visualizo que o array list retornado pela busca alunos está vazia, o
`db.insert("Alunos", null, dados);`  vejo pelo debug que chega os dados preenchidos.

Gostaria que me dessem uma luz para este problema.
Desde já agradeço a colaboração de todos.

Answer (score 0):

Faltou você apontar a referência do cursor para o início utilizando o `c.moveToFirst()`. Faça a devida modificação como demonstrado no código abaixo e veja se funciona. Qualquer dúvida, comenta aí!

```
    public List<Aluno> buscaAlunos() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Alunos;";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();//getReadableDatabase
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        c.moveToFirst(); // essa alteração deve ser feita

        List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            Aluno a = new Aluno();
            a.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
            a.setNome(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")));
            a.setEndereco(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("endereco")));
            a.setTelefone(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("telefone")));
            a.setSite(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("site")));
            a.setNota(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("nota")));
            alunos.add(a);
        }
        c.close();
        return alunos;
    }
```